# Crear archivos .bat

Tags: script, batch

Soy técnico de soporte y mi responsable me ha pedido crear 2 scripts pero no acabo de salirme.

**El primer bat**, al ejecutarlo debe hacer unas funciones concretas. Sobre un equipo nuevo, debo cambiar el nombre de equipo, crear un usuario estándar y otro administrador, deshabilitar las actualizaciones de Windows, conectarse a  una wifi (consigue crear un XLM) pero no se conecta, deshabilitar el inicio rápido y por último conectarnos a una carpeta que tenemos compartida en OneDrive descargar unas cuantas aplicaciones e instalarlas.

**El segundo bat** (diría que más fácil). Tenemos 3 equipos en las salas de reuniones. Y después de probar diversos programas para que congele el equipo una vez instalas win10 con lo básico, al final acaba dañando el sistema o son de pago. Entonces, el bat consistiría en que el usuario inicie la sesión, habla la presentación, videoconferencia (por teams) y al reiniciar el equipo que lo mantenga en el mismo punto que estaba antes de que el usuario lo iniciara (usuario limpio). Cree un punto de restauración y con el bat lo ejecuta, pero debes estar delante de la pantalla para ir siguiendo las instrucciones.

Llevo muchas semanas con esto y al final me llamaran la atención.

Os adjunto el primer BAT a ver si me ayudáis a desatascarme.

```
@echo off 
cls 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Cambio de nombre del PC 
rem --------------------------------- 
set /P NombreEquipo="Nombre del PC: " 
wmic computersystem where name="%COMPUTERNAME%" 
call rename name=%NombreEquipo% 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Usuario no administrador 
rem --------------------------------- 
set usuario1=USUARIO1 
set contrasena1=usuario  
net user %usuario1% /add %contrasena1% /expires:never 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Usuario administrador 
rem --------------------------------- 
set usuario2=administrador 
set contrasena2=0tr0s 
net user %usuario2% /add %contrasena2% /expires:never 
net localgroup administradores /add %usuario2% 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Pagina de inicio 
rem --------------------------------- 
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\RestoreOnStartupURLs" /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d http://intress.org 
rem--------------------------------- 
rem Importar Config Wifi 
rem --------------------------------- 
netsh wlan add profile filename="%~dp0W_INT.xml" user=all 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Deshabilitar Fast Startup 
rem --------------------------------- 
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 
rem --------------------------------- 
rem Apliaciones a descardat 
rem ---------------------------------**
```

Muchas gracias de antemano y un cordial saludo

Comment: Hola Jordi. El script tiene que hacer bastantes cosas. Te recomendaría que si tienes alguna duda en alguna cosa concreta, centres tu pregunta en esa cuestión. De lo contrario es bastante probable que la pregunta acabe siendo cerrada